# How to Make Sure a Security Key Still Works for My User Accounts?

Tags: security, yubico, yubikey

I have registered two Security Keys to my user accounts at e.g. Apple, Google or Microsoft.
I may not have to use them on these accounts for years.

So how do I make sure that they still work correctly for those user accounts I registered them with?

When I register them with these accounts, does something get written / stored on my security key? I.e. do I have to worry about static discharges / wrong use (e.g. resetting or wiping the key if something like this exists) or something similar that could change the stored data?
Or is this kind of use not doing any changes to the security keys? In which case maybe verifying the key is still recognized by the manufacturer's software is probably enough?

I made two assumptions, please correct me if I'm wrong:

- I use Yubikey 5c. I assume this is not relevant to my question.
- I assumed the three examples (my user account at Apple, Google, Microsoft) all use the same protocol. My Yubikey supports a bunch of protocols and I am not sure which one is used for those three.

Any advice is really appreciated, thanks!